# sort my dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this code below how could i modify to sort my dropdown list.

```
<?php
  require_once('includes/init.php');
  $all_sites = find_all('site_info');
?>
<?php

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_site'])){
   $req_fields = array('siteid');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $p_siteid   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['siteid']));
     $query  = "INSERT INTO site_table (siteid)";
     $query .=" VALUES ('{$p_siteid}')";

     if($db->query($query)){
       $session->msg('s',"Site Added ");
       redirect('site.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to add!');
       redirect('site.php', false);
     }
   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('site.php',false);
   }
 }
?>
```

My form div is showing and i think it was sorted as per column id.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form method="post" action="add_site.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <select class="form-control" name="siteid">
           <option value="">Select Site</option>
             <?php foreach ($all_sites as $site): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo (int)$site['id'] ?>">
             <?php echo $site['site_name']; ?></option>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <button type="submit" name="add_site" class="btn btn-primary">Add Site</button>
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Instead of showing like below,

```
Select Site
2001 
2000
1000
0010
0001
```

I wanted to show it like below output,

```
 Select Site
 0001
 0010
 1000
 2000
 2001
```

Thanks.

Comment: use order by Keyword while fetching $allSItes

Comment: What is `find_all('site_info');` ? can you provide the code ?

Comment: It was sql for select all. function find_all($table) {
   global $db;
   if(tableExists($table))
   {
     return find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".$db->escape($table));
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

hello Please add sort function

example [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_asort)

```
<?php asort($all_sites); ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="siteid">
               <option value="">Select Site</option>
                 <?php foreach ($all_sites as $site): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo (int)$site['id'] ?>">
                 <?php echo $site['site_name']; ?></option>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
```

Comment: This will not work as expected as the array is associative. Moreover, it is better (for performance) to sort data when querying to the database instead of sorting with PHP

Comment: Please provide us the code for find_all('site_info')

Comment: Hello Tony,
site_info is just a table.

function find_all($table) {
   global $db;
   if(tableExists($table))
   {
     return find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".$db->escape($table));
   }
}